# How additive is Lebesgue measure in ZF+AD ?

Tags: determinacy, measure-theory

What is known about the additivity of Lebesgue measure under the Axiom of Determinacy?

That is, for what cardinals $\kappa$ do we have

with $|I| = \kappa$, for all functions $f : I \to 2^\mathbb{R}$, $\; \lambda(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}\ f(i)) = \operatorname{sup}(\{\lambda(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in J}\ f(i)) : J\subseteq I \land |J|<\infty\})$.

(This is equivalent to the usual definition when $\kappa \leq \aleph_0$.)

For example:

Does it hold for $\aleph_1$?

If so, what alephs does it hold for?

Does it hold nontrivially for any infinite cardinals that are not alephs?

(nontrivially meaning sets of that cardinality can be mapped onto non-well-orderable subsets of $2^\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: I already know ZF+AD proves "For all cardinals κ, if $\kappa \leq \aleph_0$, then Lebesgue measure is κ-additive". I don't need anyone to point that out to me. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ricky:

I think I see how to answer the problem under a stronger assumption. Rather than $\mathsf{AD}$, work in $$ {\sf AD}^+ + V=L({\mathcal P}({\mathbb R})). $$ This is a bit unsatisfying, since it is very possible the question can be answered assuming only $\mathsf{AD}$. In any case, $\mathsf{AD}^+$ is potentially harmless, since it may be that $\mathsf{AD}$ implies $\mathsf{AD}^+$; but it seems strange to need here the additional machinery that $\mathsf{AD}^+$ allows us. The assumption on the form of $V$ is more immediately troublesome, since it actually makes some (non-well-ordered) cardinals "invisible". (Meaning, there may be cardinals $\tau$ that inject into $2^{|{\mathbb R}|}$ but not in $L({\mathcal P}({\mathbb R}))$, so our assumption is potentially simplifying the question.)

Using $\mathsf{AD}^+ + V=L({\mathcal P}({\mathbb R}))$, Richard Ketchersid and I proved (in *A trichotomy theorem in natural models of ${\sf AD}^+$*, in **[Set Theory and Its Applications](http://ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CONM-533)**, Contemporary Mathematics, **533**, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2011, pp. 227-258) that *every* set either is well-orderable, or is at least as large as ${\mathbb R}$. (The paper is available [here](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/conm10510.pdf), and it also provides an introduction to $\mathsf{AD}^+$.)

Obviously, Lebesgue measure is not ${\mathbb R}$-additive, considering singletons, so this means it is enough to answer the question for well-ordered cardinals. But given a well-ordered union of sets of reals, we may assume they are pairwise disjoint (arguing inductively). And then it is [standard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372218/462) that only countably many of them can be of positive measure. $(*)$

This shows (under the listed assumptions) that Lebesgue measure is $\kappa$-additive for all (well-orderable) $\kappa$ but not $\tau$-additive for *any* non-well-orderable cardinal $\tau$.

---

$(*)$ To see that the last paragraph follows, I need to argue that a well-ordered union of measure zero sets has measure zero. In fact, under $\mathsf{AD}$, a bit more holds, namely, $$ \iint_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)dydx $$ for any bounded $f:[0,1]^2\to{\mathbb R}$ (in particular, the integrals are defined).

From this it is easy to conclude the claim about measure zero sets, e.g., by looking at minimal counterexamples and adapting the standard [Sierpiński argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88811/462); note that this only uses $\mathsf{DC}({\mathbb R})$ (or even just $\mathsf{AC}_\omega(\mathbb R)$, which follows from $\mathsf{AD}$) and that all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable.

(Unfortunately, although this Fubini theorem is not too hard, I am not sure of a reference for it. I remember vol. 5 of [Fremlin's treatise](http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm) has it as an exercise.) Let me add that this is a folklore result that is frequently used, as is the dual fact that a well-ordered union of meager sets is meager under $\mathsf{AD}$.

Comment: How do you get from your second-to-last sentence to your last sentence?

Comment: No, it follows that if we have uncountably many disjoint sets, all but countably many have measure zero.

Comment: @Ricky : Sorry for the obvious gap. I added a few lines.

Comment: What is "the standard Sierpinski argument"?  Also, would Fubini hold for all nonnegative functions too?

Comment: @Ricky: Yes, it holds for bounded functions. "The standard argument" is that a measurable well-ordering of a subset of ${\mathbb R}$ must have measure 0. This is usually stated as: Under CH, a well-ordering of the reals of type $\omega_1$ is not measurable. The argument in this special case is that the sets `$\{x\mid x\lt y\}$` (where $\lt$ is the well-ordering) have measure 0 for almost all $y$ and full measure for almost all $x$, and measurability contradicts Fubini. 

Comment: *Sigh* Typo: And *the sets `$\{y\mid x<y\}$`  have* full measure for almost all $x$.

Comment: In case one wants to keep track of the assumptions: The $\kappa$-additivity for $\kappa$ a well-ordered cardinal only uses AD; the amount of choice needed (usually called $AC_\omega({\mathbb R})$) is actually provable from AD. The failure of $\tau$-additivity for $\tau$ non-well-orderable requires the additional assumptions AD${}^++V=L({\mathcal P}({\mathbb R}))$ (in particular, our proof that ${\mathbb R}$ embeds into $\tau$ uses $DC_{\mathbb R}$, and an induction through the "constructible" levels of $V$). 

Comment: @Ricky : Yes, Fubini holds for all non-negative functions, but now (both of) the integrals may be infinite.

Answer (score 4):

If $\kappa$ is a well orderable cardinal (i.e. an $\aleph_\alpha$) I don't think there is a need to involve determinacy.  If all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable (and DC holds), then Lebesgue measure is $\aleph_\alpha$ additive for every $\alpha$.
This is sufficient (at least granting DC) since AD certainly implies all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable.

First argue that if $\kappa$ is a well orderable cardinal (i.e. an $\aleph_\alpha$) and Lebesgue measure is not $\kappa$ additive, then this can be witnessed in such a way that the sets in the union are all null sets (there is a countable subcollection whose union has measure equal to the sup in your equation).  Without loss of generality, we may arrange that
$$
\lambda ( \bigcup_{\xi \in \alpha} f(\xi) ) = 0
$$
for all $\alpha \in \kappa$.  Define $Y = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa} f(\alpha)$.
Now define
$$
X = \{(x,y) \in Y^2 : \alpha_x < \alpha_y\}
$$
where $\alpha_x = \min\{\alpha \in \kappa : x \in f(\alpha)\}$.
The set $X$ now violates Fubini's theorem:
the set of all horizontal sections are the union of fewer than $\kappa$ many of the sets
$f(\xi)$ and the vertical sections have their complement (in $Y$) being the union of fewer than
$\kappa$ sets of the form $f(\xi)$.
Thus by integrating in one direction, $X$ has measure 0, while in the other direction,
its measure is $\lambda(Y)^2$.

Comment: Hi Justin. How do you argue when $\kappa$ is a non-well-orderable cardinality?

Comment: @Andres: You are right -- my answer just concerns the $\aleph$'s.  I understood that to be the main part of the question but upon reading it again, I see that isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: @Andres: I edited appropriately.

Comment: Justin, as a minor technical comment, all you need is ${\sf DC}_{\mathbb R}$, DC for sets of reals, rather than the full version of DC; this holds in all known models of determinacy, while DC fails is some of them.